# How does ios manage ViewController's memory

Tags: ios, swift

If i got three ViewControllers called VC1, VC2, VC3. And in every `ViewController`, there is lots of `ImageViews`.

If i navigate these ViewControllers like this with `pushViewController` method:

```
VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3
```

So does the memory of image allocated in VC1 will be released? 
If not, did we need to release and load image in VC1 when navigating to save memory?

Comment: What were the results of you testing this?

Comment: I haven't tested it. @rmaddy

Comment: You should do that and then update your question with relevant details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Instruments to determine you are in fact having memory issues. If so, then yes, you might try deliberately setting images to `nil` when you navigate away from a view controller. But first you should ask yourself *why* you are having memory issues. A common mistake is to use big images to display in a small UIImageView; never do that. Always resize your images to be no bigger than needed for display. If you do, it's unlikely you'll experience any memory pressure.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `navigationController?.pushViewController()` function all your view controllers are retained by navigationController. It has property `viewControllers` where you can find all the view controllers. Thus you have to do memory management by yourself. You could remove images from the image views in `viewWillDisappear()` function of your view controller and assign them again in the `viewWillAppear` function.